# How to Detect windows update(or KB update) is installed or not using NSIS?

Tags: nsis, silent-installer, windows-update

To execute my windows application, windows machine needs some pre-installed windows update(Like KB2999226 - I need to check this update). I need to install this updates with my application installer silently using NSIS.

**How to check windows has already installed particular update using NSIS.**

I have tried this [NSIS-Windows_Critical_Updates_Mass_Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Windows_Critical_Updates_Mass_Installer) but its not working. It's not able to check pre-installed update.

My windows application will run on Windows 7 SP1 and later version and windows server 2012 and later version. So i need to check updates in all this versions.

Comment: This is basically two questions. What is the official method to check if said update is installed and how do you implement this method in NSIS.

Comment: @Anders :ya.. Actually i have tried to install update using 'bat' file but unable to install it silently. My bat file code to install update is : echo off start "" wusa "$temp\WindowsUpdate\KB2937592-x86.msu". Its my second priority to install update the main is to check whether the update is already installed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether KB update is installed or not using NSIS I have used below code:

```
section

clearerrors
nsExec::ExecToStack 'cmd /Q /C "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe qfe get hotfixid | %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\findstr.exe "^KB2999226""'
Pop $0 ; return value (it always 0 even if an error occured)
Pop $1 ; command output
detailprint $0
detailprint $1

sectionend
```

To install update(.msu file) I have used below code.

```
section

clearerrors
Strcpy $strInstallPath "$temp\Updates\KB2937592-x86.msu"
Push "$temp\RunMSU.Bat"
Strcpy $0 "$temp\RunMSU.Bat"
FileOpen $0 $0 w #open file
FileSeek $0 0 END #go to end
FileWrite $0 "echo off"
FileWriteByte $0 "13"
FileWriteByte $0 "10"
FileWrite $0 "start $\"$\" wusa $\"$strInstallPath$\""
FileClose $0
Execwait "$temp\RunMSU.bat"

sectionEnd
```